# REST Template not processing &nbsp

Tags: json, spring, rest

I am working on a Spring MVC project wherein I have a web service and a web application. I am using the rest template for my web service.

When I input &nbsp in my web application it is rendered as "&nbsp" but in the web service side it becomes blank. So when I try to input &nbsp, blank is saved in the database.

Do you guys have any idea on how to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance guys. :D